# How to connect your installed academic initiative of CPLEx with python?

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I am using python 3.6 version and CPLEX 12.10 in MAC with Anaconda. How do I access the cplex libraries for python? I have an academic version installed in my MAC and can be used independently in GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to use ? There are the CPLEX python api which is a python API to the
matrix interface of CPLEX - And there is docplex, which is the object oriented modeling
layer based on CPLEX.

In anycase, if running a solve showed the error of promotional version, then it means
that somehow you installed the `cplex` package in the past.

Before you start, please open a Terminal console and make sure it is setup to use
your installation of Anaconda, and that your conda environment is activated (if you use one).

First you want to install whatever `cplex` was installed using `conda uninstall cplex`  if you installed using `conda` or `pip uninstall cplex` if you were using `pip`.

Then you have a choice. Either you add `$CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR1210/cplex/python/3.6/x86-64_osx` to your `PYTHONPATH` or you install the CPLEX python wrappers:

```
$ cd $CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR1210/cplex/python/3.6/x86-64_osx
$ python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

as said in http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/getting_started_python.html

conda install -c ibmdecisionoptimization docplex

should help

Comment: Will docplex take the academic version? I did this and it showed the error of promotion version. I already have academic initiative CPLEX installed in my mac.